# ALTER USER & PASSWORD problem via a PhP form with PostgreSQL database

Tags: php, postgresql, forms, rename, alter

I need to create a form to directly modify the usename and passwd of the pg_shadow table.

Which can only be modified with those following queries:

```sql
ALTER USER oldLogin RENAME TO newLogin;
ALTER USER newLogin WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD newPassword;
```

That being said, I wrote a User.class.php with:
User(private $_userID; private $_login; private $_password;)

Then in UserManager.class.php I wrote a:
public static function update (User $person).
This function is obviously executed when one clicks on "Modify" once the new identifiers are chosen.

Here is my function Update:

```php
public static function update(User $person)
{
    $db = DbConnect::getDb();

        $q0=$db->prepare('SELECT usename as login FROM pg_shadow u WHERE usesysid = :idUser;');
        $q0->bindValue ( ':idUser', $person->getIdUser());
        $res0= $q0->execute(); //Query to get the old usename thanks to the id.
        $old = $q0->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $q1 = $db->prepare("ALTER USER :oldLogin RENAME TO :login;");
        $q2 = $db->prepare("ALTER USER :login WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD :password;");

        $q1->bindValue ( ':oldLogin', $old['login']);
        $q1->bindValue ( ':login', $person->getLogin());
        $q2->bindValue ( ':login', $person->getLogin());
        $q2->bindValue ( ':password', $person->getPassword());

        $res1 = $q1->execute();
        $res2 = $q2->execute();
}
```

And obviously, it not works...
Could you please help me ?

Well I've tried to replace `$q1`, just for a simple test:

```
$q1 = $db->prepare("ALTER USER 'user1' RENAME TO 'newUser1';");
//It didn't work

$q1 = $db->prepare("ALTER USER user1 RENAME TO 'newUser1';");
//It didn't work

$q1 = $db->prepare("ALTER USER 'user1' RENAME TO newUser1;");
//It didn't work

$q1 = $db->prepare("ALTER USER user1 RENAME TO newUser1;");
//It work
```

Comment: You have a typo (usename instead of username) in the query. ```SELECT username as login FROM pg_shadow u WHERE usesysid = :idUser;``` Is this intentional or could that be the issue?

Comment: Yes it is intentional,
as you can see : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/view-pg-shadow.html

Comment: Oh. I see. So, what's the error you get when the method is triggered?

Comment: @Etin : Look at my new post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright,

Well I found how to make it work, thank you guys.

Here's the modifications I've made :

```php
    public static function update(User $newPerson)
    {
        $db = DbConnect::getDb();

        $idUser=$newPerson->getIdUser();
        $oldPerson=self::getById($idUser);

        $oldLogin= pg_escape_string($oldPerson->getLogin());
        $newLogin= pg_escape_string($newPerson->getLogin());

        $newPassword= pg_escape_string($newPerson->getPassword());

        $sql = "ALTER USER {$oldLogin} RENAME TO {$newLogin}; ALTER USER {$newLogin} WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '{$newPassword}';";

        pg_query($sql);

    }
```

Comment: That's much better! You can accept that answer if you like it better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are trying to use a prepared statement for `ALTER USER`. That won't work.

You'll have to construct the query string including the parameter values. User the [`pg_escape_literal`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-literal.php) function to avoid SQL injection.

Only the last of your statements without parameters will work, because user names are identifiers and not string literals, so they should be unquoted or quoted with double quotes.